# How to add previously uploaded files to new file - jQuery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I set the file input to multiple, so it can upload multiple files but the second time I click the all previous files are replaced with the new uploaded files. How can I send the all files in one go when the form is submitted?

```
#JQuery 
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple>

#Html
<a id="uploading">Upload files</a>
<a id="adding">Add files</a>
```

When the 'adding' is clicked, it calls the input file and get a new set of files.

Comment: If I’m understanding you correctly, you just need to ctrl + click to select more files one at a time or shift + click to select a range of file in a row

Comment: I added more info. What I meant was when the adding is clicked, it clicks the input file field so, there is no way to pass old files.

Comment: He dont get it yet @DelightedD0D

Comment: set the name to file[]

Answer (score 0):

I used clone to copy all the files.

```
var files= $(this).clone(true);
var fileName = $(this).val();
if (fileName) {
  $(this).parent().append(fileObjects);
}
```

It works. Anyway, thanks to all.